# .htaccess Directory Redirect Problem

Tags: htaccess

I want to redirect a directory to another directory but I've hit a snag. I want to redirect `/directory_name` to `/new_directory_name` so I put this in my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /directory_name/(.*) /new_directory_name/$1
```

Which worked fine BUT I also have another directory called:

```
/images/directory_name/
```

And the redirect is redirecting links to files in that directory to `/new_directory_name/` and resulting in broken image links.

So I need a redirect that ONLY redirects `/directory_name/` and not any other directories that happen to have the same name (but are in a different location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the subject, but I tried the following code on my server and it worked. Check it out.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.a\.com$
RewriteRule ^directory_a\/$ "http\:\/\/a\.com\/new_directory_a" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

> `RedirectMatch 301 /directory_name/(.*) /new_directory_name/$1`

You simply need to *anchor* the pattern to the start (`^`) of the URL, so it matches `/directory_name` at the start, rather than *anywhere* in the URL, which is what's happening here.

In other words, prefix the pattern with `^`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/directory_name/(.*) /new_directory_name/$1
```